# What is the purpose of $q.when in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have read the documentation of $q.when in the angularjs official docs, but I don´t understand yet what is the purpose of $q.when and its way to manage a response.

Comment: This has been asked *a lot* on Stack Overflow; please read through the multitude of questions we have on the subject, and after that; please write up a question that doesn't duplicate the other questions on this subject; or edit this question to explain how it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @f1best: see for example [Immediately return a resolved promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24794434/1048572) or [can't simply use ES6 promise to update data in ng-repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30835399/1048572)

Comment: Related: [How does Angular $q.when work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770821/how-does-angular-q-when-work)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$q.when` takes a promise or a plain value and converts it to a promise. If it already was a promise it simply returns it.

It is useful if you don't know whether the object you're dealing with is a promise or not.  For example, you might have an if/else statement where one path returns a promise but another path returns a value directly.  In that case, it would be good to use `$q.when` to handle the return such that you get a value out of it whether it's a promise or not.

For example:

```
function getData(){
    if(cachedData) return $q.when(cachedData); // converts to promise
    else return $http.get("/dataUrl"); // make HTTP request, returns promise
}
```